# how to change the value of a checkbox in angular with ControlValueAccessor

Tags: javascript, html, angular

this is my first time here, im starting speak english so i hope thath you can understand me, i do my best try.

in my directive the value "si" works, but the value "no" isnt, i need to show the value of a checkbox to "si" and "no" instead of true an false, i'm using angular and the ControlValueAccessor
interface. im using a form-group.

**this is my code on my directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
@Directive({
  selector: 'input[type=checkbox][trueFalseValue]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => VehiculosDirective),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class VehiculosDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() trueValue = true;
  @Input() falseValue = false;
  private propagateChange = (_: any) => { };

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }


@HostListener('change', ['$event'])
onHostChange(ev) {
  this.propagateChange(ev.target.checked ? this.trueValue : this.falseValue);
}
writeValue(obj: any): void {
  // model -> view
  if (obj === this.trueValue) {
    // this.elementRef.nativeElement.checked = true;
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'checked', true);
  } else {
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'checked', false);
}
}
registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
  this.propagateChange = fn;
}
registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
}

    setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    }
    }
```

**this is my vehiculoscomponent.html**

```
<div class="col-5">
                Gato <input type="checkbox"  formControlName ="gato"  trueFalseValue
                trueValue="Si" falseValue="No"
                  required>
                </div> 
              <br>

              <div class="col-5">
                Refaccion <input type="checkbox" formControlName ="refaccion" trueFalseValue
                trueValue="Si" falseValue="No" 
                  required>
                </div> 
              <br>

              <div class="col-5">
                Cruseta <input type="checkbox" formControlName ="cruseta" trueFalseValue
                trueValue="Si" falseValue="No" > 
                </div> 
              <br>

              <div class="col-5">
                Tarjeta de circulacion <input type="checkbox" formControlName ="tarjeta" trueFalseValue
                trueValue="Si" falseValue="No" 
                  required>
                </div> 
              <br>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8sUx.png)

Comment: Can yo add an example of what exactly doesn't work for you ? I tried your code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-y5wria?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts) and it seems to work fine for me.

Comment: I feel that the eror is when you define the inputs, should be "strings":`@Input() trueValue:string = "true";  @Input() falseValue:string = "false";`. NOTE: Be sure you add in "declarations" of your module the directive

Comment: sure, i already put an sreenshot of the problem